# Dropping lower order terms of a polynomial with Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Say we have this function,

f = poly(2*x**2 + 3*x - 1,x)

How would one go about dropping terms of degree n or lower.

For instance if n = 1 the result would be 2*x**2.

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, please click the "Accept" button on the top left side of the answer, so that future visitors having the same issue know the answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from sympy import poly
from sympy.abc import x

p = poly(x ** 5 + 2 * x ** 4 - x ** 3 - 2 * x ** 2 + x)
print(p)
n = 2
new_p = poly(sum(c * x ** i[0] for i, c in p.terms() if i[0] > n))
print(new_p)
```

Output:

```
Poly(x**5 + 2*x**4 - x**3 - 2*x**2 + x, x, domain='ZZ')
Poly(x**5 + 2*x**4 - x**3, x, domain='ZZ')
```